Progress tracker of implementing the scope change

On-topic help text -- updated 
Introductory paragraph of Tour -- updated
Asks and Don't Asks of Tour -- updated
Off-topic close-reasons -- updated
Update altcoin tag descriptions -- in progress
Close unanswered open questions that have become off-topic -- in progress


I've updated the introduction on the tour.
Before:


After:


I've updated the Ask & Don't Ask section of the tour.
Before:


After:


Andrew and I updated the close reasons.

Questions on current or future market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic as the answers are changing too frequently to be useful to others.
Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers. On the other hand, offerings in the Bitcoin space are still evolving rapidly which often renders answers outdated quickly. For more information see this meta-discussion.

were folded into

Questions seeking product or service reviews, current or future market values, energy costs, or service provider availability are off-topic because offerings and estimates change too quickly which renders answers outdated quickly. Furthermore, these questions tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers.

Additionally, we've added

Questions about cryptocurrencies or projects that are not Bitcoin, and are not applicable to Bitcoin, are off-topic. For more information, see this meta-discussion.

The new custom close reasons are therefore now as follows:

